# Why are there random characters outputting in my code?

Tags: c, output, symbols

I have been writing a program to input a phrase and turn it into an acronym. For some reason when I output my acronym at the moment it comes out with a bunch of random characters. How do I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 50

int main() {
    int num;

    printf("Enter number of acronyms to add to the database:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    getchar();

    char strings[num][MAXLEN];
    char acronym[num][MAXLEN];

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        printf("Enter the string to convert into an acronym:");
        fgets(strings[i],MAXLEN,stdin);
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);

        for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
            if((strings[i][j]) >= 'A' && (strings[i][j]) <= 'Z'){
                char buffer[][20] = {strings[i][j]};
                strcat(acronym[i], buffer[i]);
            }

        }
        puts(acronym[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I have tried changing the MAXLEN value to see if it was a memory issue or like a buffer overload. I've also just tried changing around how the strings switch and work together but nothing has worked.

Comment: `acronym` is uninitialized. `strcat` appends to the end of a string, so it's going to scan through the random junk until it finds a 0 and append there. Add something like `acronym[i][0] = '\0';` before the inner for loop.

Comment: Note that `strings[i]` will have a newline at the end of it unless the input line is longer than 48 bytes.  You may need to remove that before further processing.  If you don't, the `printf("%s\n", strings[i]);` will generally double-space the output.  Maybe you should also check that there is a newline present.  If not, you need to consider what to do about overlong lines of input.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[][20] = {strings[i][j]};
```

Here you let the compiler count how many elements the array has from the initialization.

It has 1 element, A string with single a single character `strings[i][j]` and rest of the 20 byte array filled with 0.

```
strcat(acronym[i], buffer[i]);
```

Here you access `buffer[i]`, but there is only one string there (as explained above), so this is invalid if `i` is anything but 0.

---

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but this would be valid implementation of what this code tries to do:

```
// extract single character as a string
char buffer[2] = {strings[i][j], 0}; // only one of 2 and 0 is mandatory
// append it to acronym
strncat(acronym[i], 20, buffer);
```

---

Probably lots of other stuff there is wrong, but here is one definite issue and a possible solution.